# Bootstrap: How to make a sidebar that expands on hover similar to gv.com

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I make a sidebar that expands on mouse hover similar to google venture's website?

http://www.gv.com

Thanks

Comment: Learn some jQuery and CSS. Doubtful anyone will give you the code unless you give a serious effort and show your work. You can learn from this file and adjust the css, js, html and post on SO when you have something close. http://jsbin.com/OjOTIGaP/1/edit